# Sending weekly emails with a list of all outstanding items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email

First, let me start with my scenario.

We have a custom SharePoint list that we use to control all our company's work. Managers will add items for the staff to do. It includes things such as the client, work required, due date and current status (Not started, in progress, completed). Each Item is also assigned a manager and an operative.

I am wanting to set up an email that will be sent to each manager each week, showing all their items that are incomplete, and either overdue, or due in the next.

I can set it up as a view, but can't seem to find a way for the email to find all items that match that criteria, it only finds the first one.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior, in SP 2007 or 2010 the workflow will only return the first match. To get all matches, you would need a more complex setup involving multiple lists or workflows, and/or flags for items that have already been retrieved.

Setting up a view seems to be the easiest way. The managers could subscribe to weekly alerts for a specific view (SP 2010).

You'll also find on Codeplex custom workflow activities - like [this project](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) - that might address your issue.

Comment: If they subscribe for weekly alerts, will that only show the items that have been changed in the past week? We don't want any jobs not worked on to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom timer job, find all the distinct managers who created an item, for each manager send a mail, query the list on created by field (and additional filter as you wish), with CAML that's an easy job, format the mail body as you wish and send the mail, that's one easy and robust solution